Installing/building local package in R using `devtools::install()` and `devtools::build()` produces "Error: HTTP error 401" error
I'm trying to install or build a package I have locally using devtools::install() and devtools::build(), but am getting the error:
Error: HTTP error 401.
  Bad credentials

  Rate limit remaining: 51/60
  Rate limit reset at: 2024-11-03 02:43:39 UTC

Every time I try, I get the same message, but the "rate limit remaining" decrements by 1 (i.e., so the next time I get 50/60), which suggests to me I have 60 tries to get this right or...?
I find this really strange, as the repo is local on my computer. Any reference I find to this issue (e.g., here) implies this error appears when trying to install from GitHub, but the package repo is local on my machine and I am not doing that.
The package is enmSdmX.

Perhaps your DESCRIPTION lists packages that you import and so R is trying to check the dependencies.  Do you list any GitHub packages, perhaps using Remotes:?

Good guess, but no--every other dependency is on CRAN.

The answer is that I needed to renew my GitHub token with usethis::create_github_token() then gitcreds::gitcreds_set(). I find this really surprising, as I wasn't interfacing with GH at all. Having done this, I could build and install without issue.
As background: I'd obtained a GH token so I could create pkgdown sites for other packages (not this package) on GH. I didn't realize it would filter down to all repos I owned.
